# Google Play crash trace de-obfuscation

Tags: android, crash, android-proguard, google-play-console

I have built my application and uploaded it to Google Play with de-obfuscation map file supplied. The `release` build is fairly trivial, i.e. I've set `minifyEnabled` to `true` and haven't modified my `proguard-rules.pro` file.

The issue I'm having is that Google Play is unable to de-obfuscate the crash traces and I keep seeing the "This mapping file was uploaded after this crash occurred. All future crashes for this version will be de-obfuscated" message. However ProGuards ReTrace which is accessible through the ProGuard GUI or `retrace.sh` is able to retrace my crash trace.

Have you encountered the same issue? How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Google Play does not "go back" and de-obfuscate stack traces that occurred prior to the mapping file being uploaded.

Comment: True, but I'm keep getting the same warning though mapping file is uploaded and new crashes aren't still de-obfuscated.

Comment: Are you sure the crash reports are from the exact same version of the app whose mapping file has been uploaded? And, of course, that you uploaded the correct file (mapping.txt)?

Comment: Yes, ProGuard's `retrace.sh` is able to un-obfuscate the trace when the same mapping file is provided

Comment: I suppose, at this point, it's possible you could be encountering a bona fide bug on Google's side. I can't offer anything further. However, I do want to point out that your answer to my second question, above, does not imply that the answer to the first is "yes". That is, just because ReTrace successfully deobfuscates a trace does NOT mean that the app version is the same as the mapping file's version. Google looks up which mapping file to use based on the app's versionCode.

Comment: Did you work out why?  I'm seeing the same... I always upload the mapping file immediately after the apk, and still get this message subsequently from users running that particular version.  Really annoying.

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same problem. I always upload the mapping file immediately after the APK so that I can debug beta test releases as well as when I push to production. Sometimes after the first crash or two, after the "uploaded after the crash occurred" message (which is incorrect) it is suddenly able to fully deobfuscate future  crashes, but more often than not it continues to fail. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the crashes are occurring for users in an old version of your app. That is why even though the crashes are new, they can't be obfuscated. Find out what version of your app the crash occurs for, and make sure the mapping file is uploaded for that version.

If the mapping file is definitely for the right version, and the crash is still not de-obfuscated, it will be a bug in the Play Console. You should contact Google Play Console support, from the help menu (behind the question mark icon) in the Play Console.

Comment: Not so in my case, you can restrict reports to current version and I still get this issue - see my comment on OP for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which I've found to be working just nicely is Google Crashlytics. It's easy to setup and it auto uploads deobfuscation map during build time. I gave upon Google PlayStore deobfuscation long time ago

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about Crashlytics?

Comment: I'd say this is the best page where you can read more on Crashlytics. https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started#android

Comment: Hmm, looks like that only works if your app includes Firebase which mine doesn't. I'll have a look into retrace.sh instead.